# aiogram бот, декоратор, сохраняющий последнее сообщение

Tags: python, aiogram

Хочу придумать декоратор для функции хендлера, который сохранял бы куда-либо сообщение, отправленное из хендлера. Пока что удалось написать вот это (предполагается, что хендлер возвращает нужное сообщение):

```
def log_prev_msg(func):
    async def wrapper(message: types.Message | types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
        args = [message, state][:func.__code__.co_argcount]
        msg = await func(*args)
        if state:
            await state.update_data(prev_msg=msg)
        return msg
    return wrapper
```

Использование:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
@log_prev_msg
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    return message.answer('какой-либо текст')
```

Но есть проблема:

```
async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
    func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Если написать так, то aiogram подставляет в функцию лишние аргументы, догадываюсь что это связано с тайп хинтами, но как это обрабатывать не понимаю. Кто-нибудь знает, что тут нужно сделать?

Comment: Возможно не связано с вашей проблемой, но у вас wrapper асинхронный, а декорируемая функция - синхронная. Одни должны быть или оба асинхронными, либо оба синхронными.

Comment: Да нет, именно wrapper должна быть асинхронной. Если сам декоратор будет асинхронным, будет ошибка

Comment: Декоратор не должен. Но сама функция cmd_start должна быть асинхронной, если wrapper внутри декоратора асинхронный. У вас внутри вызывается await func, а функция cmd_start - просто def без async.

Comment: а, это я просто опечатался. Она асинхронная в коде

Comment: По идее достаточно скопировать аннотации `wrapper.__annotations__ = func.__annotations__` перед тем как возвращать `wrapper`

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA можно просто декоратор `@functools.wraps(func)` добавить к wrapper

Comment: Действительно, `@wraps` и аннотации копирует

Comment: Спасибо, с `@functools.wraps(func)` всё заработало, но если просто `wrapper.__annotations__ = func.__annotations__`, то получается та же ошибка